# Tex with arabic letters and Pakoma

Tags: arabic, right-to-left

I'm working on books written in Arabic language, we build the book as XML file from which we generate Tex and PDF. My question is about page break, with Tex files written in English we use Pakoma program to open it, but Pakoma cant open Tex containing Arabic letters. Anyone can solve this?

Comment: A link to information about Pakoma would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Use `arabtex`, which allows you to write Arabic including diacritics using latin letters. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}

\begin{document}
\setarab

\begin{RLtext}
An ha_daA se.hr
\end{RLtext}

\end{document}
```

...which produces:

[image]

Lookup table [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArabTeX#Character_table).

Comment: `arabtex` is so last century and the font is plain ugly. I'd recommend using XeTeX (or LuaTeX if one is adventurous enough) and any nice looking font.